# Get the next target on tutorial_coach_mark

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-packages

I'm using a great coach tutorial for flutter called https://pub.dev/packages/tutorial_coach_mark

My problem is that I can get the next target only if I'm pressing on a free space on the screen. In my case I having a lot of text on the tutorial, so users are struggling to get the next target.

Is there a way to tell the TutorialCoachMark to go to the next target? So users will be able to tap on the entire screen in order to get the next target?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [@RafaelBarbosatec](https://github.com/RafaelBarbosatec/tutorial_coach_mark/issues/59#issuecomment-857811266) answer:

> What must be happening is that you are clicking on the widget that you put to display above the overlay.
> To solve this, add an IgnorePoint above the widget you pass in TargetContent.
> And don’t forget enableOverlayTab: true in TargetFocus

**Issue solved!**